# Render the value of a point in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I have managed to make a plot in R without all the thicker red lines, and the numbers (70,28), how to put it in the plot like this (I already know the values of the point that I want to display in the plot)?

[image]

Comment: Since it seems you are using base graphics, `text(x, y, "annotation")`

Comment: @hrbrmstr: i can not have the lines in red with `text`, and also the value (70,28)

Comment: you didn't specify explicitly you needed the lines, nor have you provided a reproducible example.

Comment: @hrbrmstr edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `segments` and `axis`. In the `segments` call, I use -1000 for the starting point to make sure the line goes all the way to the axis.

```
#plot values
x <-1:100
y <-seq(1,200,2)

#known point
xx <- 65
yy <- 130

plot(x,y,type="l")
segments(x0=-1000, y0=yy, x1 = xx, y1 = yy,col="red") #horiz segment
segments(x0=xx, y0=-1000, x1 = xx, y1 = yy,col="red") #vert segment
axis(1,xx,xx, col="red", col.lab="red",col.axis="red") #x-axis point
axis(2,yy,yy, col="red", col.lab="red",col.axis="red") #y-avis point
```

[image]

If you want the vertical red line to stop at 0 in the second segment (like in your example) use:

```
segments(x0=xx, y0=min(y), x1 = xx, y1 = yy,col="red") #vert segment
```

Answer (score 1):

To add intercept lines to a plot, use [`abline`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html).

`abline(v = x)` will add a vertical line at point `x`.

`abline(h = y)` will add a vertical line at point `y`.

However, these lines will span the whole plot. To stop them at their intersection, you’d need to use [`lines`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/lines.html) instead, which has slightly more complex parameters (since you need to specify both start and end coordinates).

You may also want to remove the space between the plot and the axes via `xaxs = 'i'`:

```
plot(speed ~ dist, cars, xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')
lines(c(0, 40), c(10, 10), col = 'red', lwd = 2)
lines(c(40, 40), c(0, 10), col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```

Finally, [`text`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html) can be used to insert appropriate text.